# Must declare the scalar variable error when inserting a foreign key

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-insert

I am having this problem when I'm trying to insert data into a database with a button and textboxes. Everything works fine except a foreign key that is inside the table throws this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@IDprodajalne"

I am getting kind of desperate so I really need your help now.

```
if (textBoxImeProdajalca.Text != "" && textBoxPriimekProdajalca.Text != "")
{
    try
    {
        string query = "insert into Prodajalec values (@IDProadajalne, @ImeProdajalca, @PriimekProdajalca)";

        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDProdajalne", ComboBoxIDprodajalne.SelectedItem.ToString());
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImeProdajalca", textBoxImeProdajalca.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PriimekProdajalca", textBoxPriimekProdajalca.Text);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Uspešno dodano");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Vnesite vse podatke");
}
```

And the string declarations

```
SqlConnection connection;
string connectionString;

public Form1()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Naloga.Properties.Settings.ProdajaConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
}
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy "IDprodajalne" from the error. Press Ctrl+F to search your question for it. It appears twice, both in this line:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDProdajalne", ComboBoxIDprodajalne.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

It does not appear in this line:

```
string query = "insert into Prodajalec values (@IDProadajalne,@ImeProdajalca,@PriimekProdajalca)";
```

"IDPro**a**dajalne" is a different string from "IDProdajalne". It has another "a" in it.

Fix the spelling of the one in `query`:

```
string query = "insert into Prodajalec values (@IDProdajalne,@ImeProdajalca,@PriimekProdajalca)";
```

Comment: Eagle eye over here... :)

Comment: Eagles don't use Ctrl+F! If they did, Outlook would drive them crazy.

Comment: Damn it was so easy haha. Thank you so much.

Comment: @DavidBorštner Rado pomoći